# How to access persistent data from Linux installation on USB pendrive?

Tags: live-usb, persistence

I have installed Linux Mint on USB pendrive with universal usb installer. I have also specified size of the file for persistance during installation. Is it possible to access data stored on this file without running the system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A little longer answer ...

Yes, you can ***loop mount* the file for persistence**, when the pendrive is connected to another Linux system. But Windows refuses to 'see' Linux file systems (there is probably an ext2, ext3 or ext4 file system).

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/lp1  # do this only once in your other Linux system

sudo mount -o loop /path/to/casper-rw /mnt/lp1  # loop mount
```

Replace `/path/to` with the real path in your other Linux system. Now you can access the files in your file for persistence via the mountpoint

```
/mnt/lp1
```

via command line or via a file browser.

---

Anyway, have a look at

- [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) in Linux Mint, Ubuntu or Debian,
- [Rufus](https://rufus.ie) in Windows,

that can create a ***partition* for persistence**: There is no size limit except the size of the pendrive (or SSD).

**mkusb** can also create an NTFS 'usbdata' partition alongside the partition for persistence, and this 'usbdata' partition has read/write access from both Linux and Windows.

---

**Please tell me** if you have another Linux system, or if you need access from Windows, or if there is some other problems, **and I can add details** to this answer.

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly.

Comment: @hal, You are welcome. I'm glad I could help you :-)

Comment: Windows can mount the ext4 partition if you use WSL

Comment: @phuclv, Thanks, using WSL is a good alternative :-)